# not followed by to or ing

Tags: complements

Take a look at this sentences:

1 I usually try not BE  so rude.

2 I usually try not TO be so rude.

3 I usually try not BEING so rude .

4  All I need is  TAKE  a rest .

5 All I need is TO take a rest.

6 All I need is TAKING a rest.

Which of these sentences are ok?

Is there a rule for that?

My English teacher has given me some very very ambiguous answers.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is that verb in the main clause—*try*, *need*—determines what form its complements take.

***Need*** takes **marked infinitival** complements—that is, clauses headed by a verb in the infinitive marked with *to*:

> I ***need*** **to work** harder.
>   All ***I need*** is **to work** harder.

***Try*** takes two sorts of complements.

1. In the sense you probably intend, “attempt”, as when you attempt some action without being certain you can do it, ***try*** takes **marked infinitival** complements:

   > I will ***try*** **to work** harder.
   >   I usually ***try*** not **to be** rude.
   >   I usually ***try*** **to be** polite.
2. ***Try*** has another sense, however: “test”,as when you ***try*** some action or approach to see if it is effective in reaching some other goal. In this case, ***try*** takes ***gerund-participle*** complements, headed by a verb in the *-ing* form:

   > I can’t get the ketchup out of this bottle. I’m going to ***try*** **heating** it for a few seconds in the microwave.
   >   This doesn’t work. Let’s ***try*** **using** the Schwartz-Metterklume method; some people have had great success with that.

There is no more general rule—you have to learn what complements any particular verb takes one-by-one.

Comment: So ," All I risked was losing a couple of dollars" "what we anticipated was having a hundred guests"  " the only thing I enjoyed was watching the birds"  "all I want is to be with you"  " all I need is to have a car "  are grammatically correct and common sentences?